# With $result I would be getting JSON value and with $arr I will get multidimensional array. So how can I print single value of JSON or of PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

```
<?php
$url="https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results?client_id=3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty&search=kolkata";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$arr=json_decode($result, true);
echo $arr;
?>
```

With $result I would be getting JSON value and with $arr I will get multidimensional array. So how can I print single value of JSON or of PHP?

Comment: which value do you want to print.

Comment: let us know the value of $arr & which value you want to show?

Comment: I want to get the value in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach() loop of php.

The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Note: You can further use foreach inside another foreach.

Comment: i'm getting the result like this after using this code - foreach($arr as $value){
 foreach($value as $val){
  print_r($val);
 }
}

Comment: Array ( [business_travel_reward_data] => Array ( ) [has_airbnb_plus_availability] => [has_business_travel_ready_availability] => [is_last_minute_eligible] => [last_minute_show_dist_sort] => [mobile_session_id] => uSCk0Jw_ [native_currency] => USD [price_type] => nightly [price_range_max_native] => 1000 [price_range_min_native] => 10 [search_id] => cc376106-0c42-4eba-91f4-c43491f65b90 ) Array ( [next_offset] => 20 [result_count] => 20 ) Array ( [neighborhood_facet] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => 1st Arrondissement [value] => 1st Arrondissement [count] => 3 )

Comment: now, how can I get only single value from this code

Comment: There are many data, so how many foreach will I have to use, bucause after using 3 foreach, a warning is being issued as 'invalid foreach'.

Comment: In that case you have to iterate down till you do not get the single value

Comment: I have given the code above, pls use that code and then u can see that after using 3 foreach a warning is issued. so, I cannot iterate down more further.

Answer (score 0):

In our example curl Response contain two main index 
First one is : metadata
Second one is : search_results

Example : 
     May be this code is helpful to you :

```
    - Access index value in PHP look like :

        echo $arr['metadata']['pagination']['result_count'];

    - Access index value in Json look like (usin .(dot) sign ): 

        arr.metadata.pagination.result_count;
```

Comment: in my code $result is fetching JSON data. How can I get the JSON data under the script tag??

Comment: May be you are get data using ajax request so there is a one function in our code right ??
so pass our data from function to our script